# What does a comma followed by an equals sign mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Just saw something like this in some Ruby code:

```
def getis;gets.split.map(&:to_i);end

k,=getis # What is this line doing?
di=Array::new(k){Array::new(k)}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It assigns the array's first element using Ruby's [multiple assignment](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment):

```
a, = [1, 2, 3]
a #=> 1
```

Or:

```
a, b = [1, 2, 3]
a #=> 1
b #=> 2
```

You can use `*` to fetch the remaining elements:

```
a, *b = [1, 2, 3]
a #=> 1
b #=> [2, 3]
```

Or:

```
*a, b = [1, 2, 3]
a #=> [1, 2]
b #=> 3
```

Comment: Well explained.. with other options 1+

Comment: Good explanation, though personally I'd find `k = getis&.first` (defensive against `nil`) to be a lot clearer and look less like a possible typo.

Comment: @AndrewHodgkinson that would be cleaner and you don't even need `&`. However, the code was not written by the OP ("Just saw something like this") – I therefore just explained what's going on.

Answer (score 6):

It works like this. If `lhs` has single element and `rhs` has multiple values then `lhs` gets assigned an array of values, like this.

```
a = 1,2,3  #=> a = [1,2,3]
```

Whereas if `lhs` has more elements than `rhs`, then excess elements in `lhs` are discarded

```
a,b,c = 1,2 #=> a = 1, b = 2, c = nil
```

Therefore

`a, = 1,2,3 #=> a = 1`. The rest i.e. [2,3] are discarded

Comment: lhs #left-hand side (of an equation)